# Disable webcrawling in splunk server

Tags: web-crawler, splunk, googlebot

I using [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) cloud service, but I am regularly getting crawled by web-bots which is taking information and increasing web traffic. 
How can I disable web crawling?

Comment: To add proper [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) ? Anyway, some of robots may ignore it and the only way to block them is to use firewall.

Comment: Cool. How can they login and extract information?